# Can I Use Local Business Schema Without Google My Business

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, google-search, google-my-business

There is any way to use Local Business Schema without Creating a business profile on google my business.

How to use Schema and where to place this code on the website.

should we do or not?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "LocalBusiness",
  "name": "",
  "image": "",
  "@id": "",
  "url": "",
  "telephone": "",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "",
    "addressLocality": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "addressCountry": ""
  }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking if using that schema on your site would automatically create a Google business listing?

Comment: thanx actually, I know the process of creating GMB. But, I am asking without creating a GMB Listing, Can I use local business schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can, and should, use this schema regardless of whether you have a Google My Business listing. (Although if you have a brick and mortar location, you should create a GMB listing too.)

Use this schema on your website's page for the business. If your whole website is dedicated to this location, you can put this on the home page. If you have different locations, put this on the page for each location. You can include more than one script if your page lists numerous locations.

The code goes in the `<head>` of the document.

Your `@type` value would change depending on what sort of business it is; you'd have to consult the [Google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business) on the possible values.